# Cannot install apache2 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver, apache2, google-compute-engine

I deploy a Google Cloud Compute Engine small Instance. But I want to run an Apache2 Web Server on that instance. When it install by apt-get installer, at the end it says,

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
```

invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ..

When it start the service it says,

```
Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

`(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.`

I allowed HTTP and HTTPS Firewall rules

What is missing there? Please help..

Comment: Post the output of `# netstat -tupelan | grep 80`.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24916      -

Comment: Strange. The last column should contain ID and the name of the process which is listening on port 80, but it is not there. Try rebooting the instance and, maybe, check the Apache config with `# apachectl -t`.

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK